# Dirichlet characters modulo $2^v$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all Dirichlet characters modulo $2^v$ , $v\in \mathbb N$

How Iam supposed to do this? if i had $mod 4$ ,it would be quite easy. $\phi(4)=\phi(2^2)=2$

$\chi(0)=\chi(2)=0 ,\chi(1)=1 , \chi(3) =\pm 1$

Please help me:D

Comment: Come on, Dirichlet comes with a big D. :D

Comment: i dont understand? :/

Comment: Dirichlet was a mathematician. Therefore spelled with a big D.